# Entity Framework Core C# : I have a problem with a object in an List object I include in my generated Get statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, rest

I have a problem: I use a C# REST API for my frontend but I have a list of objects that I can't seem to add to my object I return a get all:

```
    // GET: api/OrderMasters
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<OrderMaster>>> GetOrderMasters()
    {
        return await _context.OrderMasters
                             .Include(x => x.OrderDetails)
                             .ToListAsync();
    }
```

This is the statement; I include the order details but inside the order details I want to add the foodItem; I already have a controller for my food items and it is in my DB context

[image]

This is the return I get when I get all and you see the food item = null but the order details is a list of OrderDetail inside OrderMaster

I've tried different things like this:

```
var orderDetails = await (from master in _context.Set<OrderMaster>()
                          join detail in _context.Set<OrderDetail>()
                               on master.OrderMasterId equals detail.OrderMasterId
                          join foodItem in _context.Set<FoodItem>()
                               on detail.FoodItemId equals foodItem.FoodItemId
                          select new
                                 {
                                     master.OrderMasterId,
                                     detail.OrderDetailId,
                                     detail.FoodItemId,
                                     detail.Quantity,
                                     detail.FoodItemPrice,
                                     foodItem.FoodItemName
                                 }).ToListAsync();

            // get order master
            var orderMaster = await (from a in _context.Set<OrderMaster>()
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         a.OrderMasterId,
                                         a.OrderNumber,
  
                                         a.PaymentMethod,
                                         a.GrandTotal,
                                       
                                         orderDetails = orderDetails
                                     }).ToListAsync();
```

This is what I found on the internet the closest fix I could get but it gave some weird errors so I try to fill the object food item inside a list of orderdetails that is inside the object ordermaster any idea how to fix this I searched over stack overflow but I didn't know how to find this problem so hopefully someone knows a thread to fix this or someone knows the answer.

So the thing is: how do I fill food items?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`ThenInclude()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-5.0) after you call `Include()` where you select the inner property of `FoodItem`.

```cs
    // GET: api/OrderMasters
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<OrderMaster>>> GetOrderMasters()
    {
        
        return await _context.OrderMasters.Include(x=> x.OrderDetails).ThenInclude(x => x.FoodItem).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Considering that you have a field named `FoodItem` in your `OrderDetails` class and that you have set up the `DbContext` correctly to know the foreign keys of each table.